# Using reusable function to check if array instead of Array.isArray in typescript throws error

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, if I use this,

```
Array.isArray(value) ? [value] : value
```

...it works fine. But if I use a utility function to check it if is array then Typescript complains with error message `Argument of type Item[] | Item[][] is not assignable to type Item | Item[]`.

```
const isArray = (value: any) => Array.isArray(value)

isArray(value) ? [value] : value // Throws error
```

Comment: Try `const isArray = (value: any): value is any[] => Array.isArray(value)`

Comment: Why not just `const { isArray } = Array`? Given that the function only does that one thing. Or is that just an example?

Comment: @LionelRowe That's just my personal preference to have like all the utility functions in one file be it as simple as checking array, string, and so on... 

Comment: In that case yeah, just use `const { isArray } = Array`. No need to create a new function just to call an existing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const isArray = (value: any): value is any[] => Array.isArray(value)
```

You can learn about this [more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)